# Finding 4 numbers in a row and then cutting the rest of the sting python

Tags: python, string

I was wondering how I would a go about detecting 4 digits in a row in a string and then removing the rest (everything after) the 4 digits

this is the code I'm using right now:

```
import os
import shutil

videoFileExtensions = [".mkv", ".flv", ".mp4", ".avi", ".mov", ".wmv"]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("E:\Movies"):
    for file in files:
        for extensions in videoFileExtensions:
            if extensions in file:
                tempStr1 = root + os.sep + file
                total_occurances = tempStr1.count('.')
                tempStr2 = tempStr1.replace(".", " ", total_occurances-1)

                print(tempStr2)
```

this is what I am getting:

> ```
> E:\Movies\Alien (1979) x 1600 (2160p) Theatrical HDR 5 1 x265 10bit Phun Psyz.mkv 
> ...
> ...
> ...
> ```

this is what I want:

> *E:\Movies\Alien 1979.mkv  ... ... ...*

any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: does any one know how I would get just the numbers without the brackets?

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions.

```py
import re

# This assumes that there are parentheses surrounding the digits.
tempStr1 = 'Alien (1979) x 1600 (2160p) Theatrical HDR 5 1 x265 10bit Phun Psyz.mkv'
temp = re.match(r'\A(.+?) \((\d{4})\)', tempStr1)
title = temp.group(1)  # 'Alien'
year = temp.group(2)  # '1979'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
tempStr2 = tempStr1.split(')')[0] + ')' + extensions
```